# Can't use InkCanvas in SilverLight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, inkcanvas

I am trying to create my first program in SilverLight. But I can't use the InkCanvas.

Simply, I just:

1. Create a new project.
2. Choose SilverLight Application (Framework 4.5)
3. UnCheck "Host the silverlight application in a website..."
4. SilverLight version 5
5. "WCF RIA Services" unchecked
6. Click on ToolBox > Choose Items > Select InkCanvas from SilverLight components
7. Add InkCanvas to the form & Change it's background color to black
8. Click on "Start" (Debug)

But I can't see or use the Canvas.

Here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:Workspace="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Workspace;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Runtime"
             x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.MainPage"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="White">
    <Workspace:InkCanvas HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Height="204"
                         Margin="36,52,0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Width="310"
                         Background="Black" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then I get these 2 errors:

> Error 1   Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a
>   namespace 'Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Workspace' that could not
>   be found. c:\users\xperator\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\SilverlightApplication3\SilverlightApplication3\MainPage.xaml   6   21  SilverlightApplication3

and

> Error 2   The type 'Workspace:InkCanvas' was not found. Verify that you
>   are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
>   assemblies have been built.   c:\users\xperator\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\SilverlightApplication3\SilverlightApplication3\MainPage.xaml   12  10  SilverlightApplication3

As the error says, there is no `Workspace` in the Prototyping namespace. I can see in the Solution explorer, there is only 2 References related to the InkCanvas:

> Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Interactivity
>
> microsoft.expression.prototyping.runtime

Tried to add the "Workspace" from the "Add Reference" but couldn't find it.

UPDATE :

I think actually the InkCanvas is not official ported to silverlight yet. Tried to do the same steps on a fresh pc, and I just noticed InkCanvas wasn't there in the first place. Maybe something related to Blend added the prototype control in my own PC. Still it doesn't work :(

I am open to any suggestion for alternatives to InkCanvas.

Comment: i think you should check for toolkit reference is that proper add or not?

Comment: or you should visit this link : http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/tip-of-the-day-102/

Comment: @Jignesh I updated my post. And you seem to be mistaken WPF with SilverLight. The link you posted is a WPF article.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use InkCanvas instead of [InkPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903958%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)? The latter should work in Silverlight.

Comment: @keyboardP I want to create an Online Collaboration Whiteboard. As far as I know, InkPresenter doesn't come with prebuilt drawing/editing functions like InkCanvas. I think it's pretty much same as the Canvas.  So I got to implement all the fucntions by myself. Am I right?

Comment: @xperator - I'm not too familiar with either but you do have to handle a lot of the drawing functions yourself with the InkPresenter. Fortunately, it's not too tricky for basic strokes (http://www.thedatafarm.com/silverlightink/ - although it's JS, the C# code is similar) but more complex functions may require more work than on an InkCanvas.

Comment: You have sample code of erase (and other) fct in msdn sample : http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/samplebrowser/index.htm#/?sref=InkPointErase